# Visual Studio - when to call update on a tableadapter

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm new to Visual Studio - migrating from Microsoft Access and Dynamics AX where updates to physical tables happen pretty much automatically for a simple data grid.

In my Visual Studio VB form project I have a datagrid component bound to a tableadapter. I can double-click a cell and edit the contents, then move to another row. But my changes are not being committed to the dataset's table.

Even though the tableadapter has an update method, apparently it is not called automatically. Do I have to call the tableadaptor's update method to save the user's data changes in the grid?

If so, how do I detect when datagrid cells values have been changed? Or do I simply call update every time the user leaves a row and let the update query run even with no changes?